# Jquery mobile Where and how exacly insert prevent default behavior on list items?

Tags: android, iphone, jquery-mobile

In dynamically generated list I need to stop `Click`(tap) Event if I `scroll` in list.

I tried add to document.ready function

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  })
```

But it does not working for me.
Could  somebody help me?
In all link I using `onTouchEnd` event.

Comment: can you possibly post your code? I just tried your code in my own sample webpage and it worked fine for me (the link doesn't work because `event.preventDefault();` prevented it). Also if you could look in the console and tell us any errors that'd be very helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you are preventing the default behavior of any link that exists at the moment you execute that statement. If the list (of links, I guess) is generated dynamically, you should bind the handler like this:

```
$(document).on('click','a', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Be aware that you would be attaching this handler to any link in the document. If you just want to apply it to a group of links, you could either change `$(document)` for the selector of the parent that contains them and already exists, or change `'a'` for something more specific, like a selector that includes a class de have in common.

Comment: I changed onclick to ontouchend and is it faster, but now i have very big problem with ghost click (touch) (and then loading detail) on list item if if list is filled and page is changed (via changePage method). Is it possible to solve it?